# Error when using Presto's date functions: '>=' cannot be applied to varchar, date

Tags: presto-jdbc

I am facing an issue while using presto date functions to get the current day and the previous day’s data.

> “An error occurred while communicating with Presto.
> Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
> Error Code: 9F80FB23
> [Simba][Presto] (1060) Presto Query Error: line 30:37: '>=' cannot be applied to varchar, date (1)
> [Simba][Presto] (1060) Presto Query Error: line 9:24: '>=' cannot be applied to varchar, date (1)”

Can you please help /suggest us to resolve it?

```
*where a.event_date <= current_date
*where a.event_date <= date 'current_date' - interval '1' day
```

Answer (score 1):

> line 9:24: '>=' cannot be applied to varchar, date (1)

There is no `>=` in the query you provided,
However, i am guessing `event_date` is a varchar column, so you want something like this:

```
CAST(a.event_date AS date) <= current_date - interval '1' day
```